# Am I correct in terms of understanding gradient and covector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, dual-spaces, divergence-operator

Well actually I know what gradient is and what that means. My professor once said that gradient is actually a covector in passing. As I know, covector is a linear map that maps vector to a scalar but gradient maps scalar to a vector.

So I guess he meant divergence $ \nabla \cdot $, not gradient $ \nabla $.

By that way, it does make sense considering $ \nabla $ is a vector $ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x^3} & \cdots & \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n} \end{pmatrix} $ and dot product is defined as $ v^T $ when operating a vector to another vector.

Am I correct or is there something I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: In short: in linear algebra, column vectors are vectors and row vectors are covectors. This is just to make the matrix multiplication work when we take a scalar product. In differential geometry and its little sister multivariable calculus, $\partial_i$ are basis vector (fields) and $dx^i$ are their covector fields.

Comment: To complete this: the gradient of a function $f(x)$ is a linear map that approximates $h\mapsto f(x+h)-f(x)\,.$ As such it can be written in scalar product form as $\nabla f(x)\cdot h$ where $h$ is a column vector and $\nabla f(x)$ a row vector (covector).

Comment: But doesn't scalar product of two vectors also result in scalar value? According to my limited knowledge, to be a covector, shouldn't 'matrix multiplication' between the value and a vector should result in a scalar? Please tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: That's totally right. Since $\mathbb R^n$ is isomorphic to its dual, it is a bit of an overkill to insist that the gradient  of a function is a covectors and not a vector. The sharp distinction between these notions becomes much more important in  DG when we look at coordinate transformations. A subject in itself.