# Which is the correct definition of covectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, definition, tensors, covariance

Some says covectors are linear map that maps $ V \mapsto R $ (which means it's just a row vector considering vectors are $ n $ x $ 1 $ matrix and mapping is matrix multiplication), while some say it's a certain value whose components follow $ v'_i = \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^i} v_j $ under coordinate transformation from $ x $ coordinate to $ x' $ coordinate.

Let's see gradient for example.

$ \nabla $ itself is not a map $ \nabla : V \mapsto R $, but divergence, $ \nabla \cdot $ is. So $ \nabla $ is not a covector of first definition.

However, considering $ \nabla $'s components are $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $, they actually follow the transformation rule by $ \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x'^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^j} $. So it's a covector of the second example.

---

Which one's right? Are they actually the same definition and I'm misunderstanding something or are they just different things I'm talking about?

Comment: See my comments to a very recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872003/am-i-correct-in-terms-of-understanding-gradient-and-covector#comment10388628_4872003).

Comment: $\nabla$ itself is not a vector or covector. You could call it a vector-valued operator. Given a scalar function $f$, its differential $$\begin{bmatrix} \partial_1f & \cdots & \partial_nf \end{bmatrix}$$ is a covector. The transpose of the differential is the gradient $\nabla f$.

Comment: I think you are mixing up *covectors* and *covector fields*. The latter is a function whose value at each point of a manifold is a covector of the tangent space

Comment: @KurtG. I saw that and that helped me alot(thank you). However, I was stuck again looking around different sources. I guess I need 'the sharp distinction' you've mentioned.

Comment: @Deane So are differential and gradient both covectors or only differential is? Does transposing actually make difference in this context?

Comment: @Didier I don't think that will actually make a difference, since I can just correspond covectors to form a 1-form.

Comment: @posfn0319 It does. Your first definition "linear map $V \to \mathbb R$" is that of a covector, the second one "something that transforms as..." is a (bad, in my opinion) definition of a covector field (which is the same thing as a 1-form)

Comment: @Didier But isn't the second definition from a definition of tensors, not tensor fields?

Comment: @posfn0319 If you have coordinates and partial derivatives with respect to these coordinates, then you have an underlying manifold and you are looking at tensor fields

Comment: Differential is a row matrix and therefore a covector. Gradient is a column vector and therefore a vector. The differential defines a linear function from vectors to scalars using matrix multiplication. You could use the gradient to do this but then you have to either use the dot product or take the transpose (I.e., use the differential). Does all of this make any difference? Not unless you want to do everything in a coordinate free way and avoid using the dot product or transpose, which you need to do when you learn a more abstract version of multivariable calculus.

Comment: I haven’t been distinguishing carefully between covectors and covector fields (also known as 1-forms).

Answer (score 5):

REPLY TO COMMENT:

A vector field with respect to coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$ is of the form $$ V = v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}. $$ Therefore, if we do a change of coordinates, where we view the old coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$ as functions of the new coordinates $(\bar{x}^1, \dots, \bar{x}^n)$, then coordinate vector fields are related by $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^j} = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\bar{x}^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.$$ Therefore, $$ V = v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \bar{v}^j\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}^j}, $$ where $$ v^i = \bar{v}^j\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\bar{x}^j}. $$ On the other hand, with respect to the coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$, the gradient of $f$ is the vector field $$\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $$ and the gradient of $f$ with respect to $(\bar{x}^1,\dots,\bar{x}^n)$ is $$\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{x}^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^j} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar x^i}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\bar{x}^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}.$$ Observe that in the general, the two formulas for $\nabla f$ conflict. They do not give the same vector field. On the other hand, if you compute $df$ with respect to each set of coordinates, you find that the two formulas *do* match.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The point of distinguishing a covector from a vector is to avoid any dependence on coordinates. Why do this? Because the geometric and physical properties of space should not depend on coordinates (e.g., whether you use inches or meters to determine distance or position).

One way to do this is to write everything initially in terms of coordinates and then show that the formulas change in the right way under a change of coordinates.

An alternative way is to not use coordinates at all. We also initially try to avoid using the dot product (this is a special case of what it known as a Riemannian metric). The differential versus gradient of a function is a good example.

You should think of the differential of a function as a way to represent the directional derivatives of a function. To simplify things but emphasize the coordinate independence, let's view $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an abstract vector space.

The directional derivative of a function $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at $x \in V$ in a direction $v$ is defined to be the following: Given any curve $c: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow V$ such that $c(0) = x$ and $c'(0) = v$, let
$$ D_vf(x) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(c(t)). $$
There are the following facts: This definition does not depend on the curve $c$ used, and, if $f$ and $x$ are held fixed, the function
$$ v \mapsto D_vf(x) $$
is a linear function from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It therefore is a covector, which is called the **differential** of $f$ at $x$ and denoted $$df(x): V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$ In particular, $df(x)$ is an element in the dual space $V^*$. The map $x \mapsto df(x)$ is an example of what is known as either a covector field or $1$-form.

Note that everything above used no coordinates or basis on $V$.

Note that there is no analogous way to define the gradient $\nabla f$ in a similar coordinate-independent way. You have to either choose a basis of $V$ or an inner product on $V$. Either way, you get a linear isomorphism $V^* \rightarrow V$. This allows you to map $df(x)$ to an element in $V$, which is known as the gradient of $f$ at $x$. The gradient defines a map $x \mapsto \nabla f(x)$, which is an example of a vector field.

You don't always want to do this, so that's why modern abstract differential geometry carefully distinguishes vectors and vector fields from covectors and $1$-forms. Later, when Riemannian metrics are introduced, then the gradient of a function reappears.

Comment: I got that differential indeed is 1-form and now that's clear thanks to you. I got the notion. But I have one more question. I now understand that gradient maps $ V \mapsto V $ so it's rather a vector field than a 1-form. However, it still 'changes in the right way'(which is different of vector fields' it) you said and that still bothers me.

If I'm making you frustrated, I'm sorry. My understanding capability is not good I guess. Upvoted.